# Evitar login con el boton de volver del navegador en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, login, session

Bien, tengo un problema que no logro resolver.

Estoy usando el sistema de autenticación que ofrece Laravel, cuando ingreso me envía a la pagina de home (diferente para cada tipo de usuario) hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es que si le doy click al botón de `volver` del navegador, vuelve a la pagina de login, y no quiero que eso suceda, y me gustaría validar que, si existe un `user_id` activo, me redirija a una pagina genérica (home, por ejemplo).

Por ahora, logre controlar que cuando ponen la url de `MyWebSite/Login` o `MyWebSite/` me redirija a una pagina generica.

En el archivo ´web.php´ añadi esto, has lo mismo con el Login.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

Route::get('/',function(Request $request){ 

        if(!$request->User()) {
                return view('auth.login');
        }else{
            return redirect ('LA PAGINA QUE DESEO REDIRIGIR');
        }
});
```

Esto me funciona genial cuando ponen directo la URL en el navegador, pero no cuando le dan click al bendito boton de volver atras.

Answer (score 0):

Este es tema de middlewares

Para proteger tus rutas y que solo los usuarios autenticados puedan entrar a ella lo correcto es que protejas tus rutas mediante middlewares ejemplo

```
    Route::get('/flights', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may access this route...
})->middleware('auth');
```

Para modificar hacia donde deben de ser redirigidos los usuarios no autenticados lo puedes hacer modificando el mismo middleware el cual se encuentra en:

> app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

esta es la configuración por defecto

```
  protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        return route('login');
    }
```

Si tienes al alguna otra duda tu mejor opcion es revisar la documentacion de laravel
[Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#introduction)

Comment: Claro, como dije, lo de redirigir a mis usuarios no autenticados ya lo tengo cubierto, osea cuando intentan ingresar a una URL cualquiera, verificara si el usuario activo en ese instante tiene o no los permisos de acuerdo a su Rol. Mi problema es solo que no quiero que el `botón de volver` (la flechita atrás) del navegador permita volver hasta el Login nuevamente cuando hay algun usuario activo. Mi problema es con la flechita, no con las autenticaciones.

Comment: SI tu manera de redireccionar a los usuarios no autenticados es como muestras en tu código de ejemplo quiere decir que no haces uso de middlewares 
al no hacer uso de ellos pierdes eso que tu estas buscando  que los usuarios NO autenticados puedan entrar al login y los usuarios autenticados son redirigidos a la pagina HOME por defecto  porque de todo eso se encargar el middleware "auth"
si el usuario esta autenticado y aun el quiera entrar /login directamente el middleware no lo permite o si le da atras o como sea que quiera entrar

Comment: La verdad es que no se si estoy usando el middelware ¿Como puedo hacer para verificar eso? Yo creé directamente el sistema de login desde la consolsa usando el Auth y esto ya me creó todos los controladores y demas, tambien las verificaciones, yo solo modifique un poco. En la carpeta de middelware hay uno llamado `RedirectIfAuthtenticate`, supongo que te refieres a ese, porque dentro hay una funcion `handle` que verifica si el usuario esta autenticado y lo redirige a `/home`. 
Ahora, sinceramente no sabria decirte si este middleware esta siendo ocupado o no. Hay alguna forma de saberlo?

Comment: De todas formas, el problema no se si se llegaría a resolver usando el middleware, debido a que el boton de `volver atras` de cada navegador devuelve a la vista almacenada en caché, y esa vista no hace una peticion al servidor. (Si no me equivoco creo que es asi) 
Por otro lado, si me gustaria saber como implementar o usar el middleware en lugar de la forma que estoy usando para el redireccionamiento. Si pudieses ayudarme con eso te lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0):

Agregale a la ruta de login el middleware `guest`, este middleware hace que solo puedas acceder a cierta ruta si no estas autenticado. Si intentas acceder, te redireccionara a la ruta especificada en la constante `HOME` en `RouteServiceProvider`.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bien, de hecho, ya encontré la ruta que me especificaste y pues, resulta que si esta implementando el Middleware. `$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');`
Ahora, de nuevo, les digo, el sistema de login funciona correctamente, si no estoy logueado no me deja acceder a las rutas. Todo eso funciona bien, mi problema es otro, tiene mas que ver con las vistas almacenadas en la caché. Cuando ingreso con un usuario x, me redirige a una pagina especifica, pero si le doy a volver con el boton, pues me carga la vista de login nuevamente, y eso es lo que no quiero.

Answer (score 0):

tenia el mismo problema lo que me funciono fue:
en el archivo kernel.php en el metodo $middlewareGroups en la seccion web agregar \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,

y en el controlador de mi login agregar el metodo

```
public function showLoginForm()
    {
        // Desactivar el almacenamiento en caché para la página de inicio de sesión
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");

        return view('auth.login');
    }
```

en mi caso estoy usando laravel con adminlte3 y lo agregue despues de

```
 public function __construct()
    {
      
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
```